# Recommendation of a comprehensive book on the history of medicine

Tags: history

I was wondering if somebody could recommend a book on the history of medicine, be it comprehensive or an introduction to the history of medicine. I know there are a lot of medical books that cover this subject, but given that I have a limited amount of time for reading I was wondering which book would make the best use of my time.

Answer (score 2):

While it's not meant to be a history of all of medicine, I thought the [The Emperor of All Maladies](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439107955) touched on a good deal of the history as the author took us through how cancers were diagnosed and treated since long ago.

Great book, that was.

Answer (score 1):

[I enjoyed "Doctors: the biography of Medicine" by Sherwin Nuland](http://books.google.com/books?id=hVePdRGsX2sC&printsec=frontcover&dq=doctors%20the%20history%20of%20medicine&source=bl&ots=nDEwXGoe0i&sig=urP38zlQn2Ypq_IMQUc2N6zBzbg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4IQuUPCJJ9POyAG85oDAAQ&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=doctors%20the%20history%20of%20medicine&f=false)

It is not comprehensive, but covers the major eras of medicine.

Im sure there are many others.